# Python code erroring when whole .py file is run but runs fine when executed line by line

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, spyder, google-bigquery-storage-api

I am trying to load data from big query table to a snowflake table using python via Spyder.
This code runs fine when I execute it line by line but when I try to run the whole file, I get an error saying "**NameError: name 'df' is not defined**" at the write_pandas section.
It seems to say that df is not defined and get_ipython hasnt created it. But that's not true and it does create a data frame df after the line is executed. Any help to bypass this error check?

(Note: I tried defining the data frame(df = pd.DataFrame()) before I run these two lines but write_pandas seems to error out when i do that. "**Error: ValueError: range() arg 3 must not be zero** ")

Code:

```
#Get the table data and put in df dataframe
get_ipython().run_cell_magic('bigquery', 'df', 'SELECT * FROM `Table`')

#load to snowflake
success, nchunks, nrows, _ = write_pandas(cnx, df, 'Table' , quote_identifiers= 0)
```

Comment: Post the whole error message, including complete stack trace.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File \\fileAPI.py:68 in <module>
    success, nchunks, nrows, _ = write_pandas(cnx, df, 'Home' , quote_identifiers= 0)

NameError: name 'df' is not defined

Comment: And error when i try to define the data frame before running these two lines:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File \\fileAPI.py:68 in <module>
    success, nchunks, nrows, _ = write_pandas(cnx, df, 'Home' , quote_identifiers= 0)

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\envname\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\pandas_tools.py:161 in write_pandas
    for i, chunk in chunk_helper(df, chunk_size):

  File ~\Anaconda3\envs\envname\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\pandas_tools.py:34 in chunk_helper
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):

ValueError: range() arg 3 must not be zero

Comment: can you show what `df` is ?